# What are the differences between golf and hiking/outdoor waterproofs?

Tags: waterproof-clothing

I have recently taken up golf but have been a keen hiker/outdoorsman for a while.

I am struggling to find a compelling reason to invest in "golf-specific" waterproof clothing.

Is there any reason why a waterproof wind cheater jacket for hiking is fundamentally different from a waterproof golf jacket?

Comment: Golf specific clothing is stupid expensive, and will likely get torn to shreds as soon as you take it into the woods.

Comment: @ShemSeger you have mistaken the question.  I am not looking for a reason to take a golf waterproof into the wild...I am looking for a reason why a North Face waterproof lightweight jacket will not work on a golf course.

Comment: @Venture2009 - No I get the question, I was stating that golf stuff light and thin, much like your wallet is after you buy it. Mattnz provides a good answer. Only invest in the golf stuff after you've reached a level where you notice the outdoor stuff is interfering with your stroke.

Answer (score 8):

Reason a) Golf is synonymous with a form of fashion, to play Golf you must be wearing the 'correct' (i.e. insanely expensive) clothing. Some Golf courses have a high required standard of dress and although not breaking the rules, non-Golf specific gear is frowned on. Other courses are more relaxed and as long as you don't wear your crampons on the green they don't care.

Reason b) A Golf jacket is likely cut differently to minimize the  effect on the swing. At sub 20 handicap it makes a difference if you swing is altered by wearing a jacket. Starting out, there are more important things to worry about and the jacket will not make a measurable difference to your game.

If you are a cyclist this is exactly same as the Lycra requirement on road bikes. Once you reach a certain level you splash out on the specific gear the 'rules' of the sport dictate you must have, so you fit in and have the  gear to maximize your enjoyment of the sport.